# Uninstalled mendeley but the citation plugin still appears in word

Tags: mendeley

I have uninstalled Mendeley on my Mac but the citation plugin still shows up in word. I have restarted my computer numerous times but still there. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions would be helpful!

I have restarted my computer numerous times but still there. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here, as it's not at all related to programming. Perhaps ask about it on SuperUser? (though I'm not sure it would be on-topic there either, as there isn't much detail to go on)

Answer (score 9):

You can uninstall the MS plugin on Mendeley Desktop > Tools > Uninstall MS Word Plugin.

In your case, as you already uninstall the Mendeley Desktop, there's a way to remove by hand. According [this thread/user](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.office.misc/F2mxkXGeEdU/UZQrAhfC9tAJ), the steps are:

- Open up Word and click on the main menu in the top left, and then
  select "Word Options" towards the bottom of this menu.
- From here
  select "Add-Ins" on the left, and locate the "Mendeley-0.0.0.dot"
  entry. The 0.0.0 number will reflect the respective version you have
  installed. Next to it you will see the directory in which it is
  located. This directory might be hidden. In Mac, you can use Shift+Cmd+. to display the hidden files and folders.

[Here](http://guides.library.illinois.edu/mendeley/desktop) you can see more information about that too ("Citing Items in Word with the MS Word Plugin").

Comment: I have Word for Mac 16 and the Mendeley add-in can be removed under: Tools -> Template and Add-Ins... -> (mark Mendeley and click "-")